# Golang pointer confusion, how to get a pointer from a function, and pass forthur to a modifying function

Tags: go, pointers

I want to use library (golang walk declarative) that expects me to pass a pointer variable and the library will populate it with an instance later.

For bookeeping purposes, I tried to create a function that will return the reference and pass it further, but In the original function I am not getting back the reference to the correct object.

I tried to simplify the problem, but I am still unable to get it right, How could I get the value world to be populated in the map, within the test_ref struct, without modifying the setup function.

Working code

```golang
var t *walk.LineEdit
...
                    LineEdit{
                        AssignTo: &t,
                    },
```

My attempt

```
                    LineEdit{
                        AssignTo: GetLineEdit("msg"),
                    },
...
func GetLineEdit(name string) **walk.LineEdit {
```

Test code

```
type test_ref struct {
    v map[string]*string
}

func (t *test_ref) init() {
    t.v = map[string]*string{}
}

func (t *test_ref) return_ref() **string {
    s := "hello"
    t.v["a"] = &s
    p := t.v["a"]
    return &p
}

type test_setup struct {
    s **string
}

//dont modify this function
func setup(t test_setup) {
    w := "world"
    *(t.s) = &w
}

func main() {
    tr := test_ref{}
    tr.init()
    s := tr.return_ref()
    setup(test_setup{
        s: s,
    })
    fmt.Println(*tr.v["a"])//logging hello

}
```

If I make a small modification to the setup function, I could get it to work, but since I do not want to update the walk library I wonder if there is a way to do it without touching the the setup function.

```golang
func setup(t test_setup) {
    w := "world"
    **(t.s) = w
}
```

Comment: There is no pointer arithmetic here (or in golang)

Comment: Correct, I meant pointer difficulty,  in C that category includes pointer confusions, segfaults, arithmatic, and race conditions, thanks for the correction, I am updating the question header as people searching might not make that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
func (t *test_ref) return_ref() **string {
    s := "hello"
    t.v["a"] = &s
    p := t.v["a"]
    return &p
}
```

what you are returning is the address of the variable `p`.

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
func (t *test_ref) return_ref() *string {
    s := "hello"
    t.v["a"] = &s
    return &s
}
```

Above will return the address of `s`, which is what's stored in the map. Then:

```
type test_setup struct {
    s *string
}

func setup(t test_setup) {
    w := "world"
    *t.s = w
}
```

This will set the value of the string to "world".

You can take this a degree further and do:

```
type test_ref struct {
    v map[string]**string
}

func (t *test_ref) init() {
    t.v = map[string]**string{}
}

func (t *test_ref) return_ref() **string {
    s := "hello"
    k := &s
    t.v["a"] = &k
    return &k
}

type test_setup struct {
    s **string
}

// dont modify this function
func setup(t test_setup) {
    w := "world"
    *(t.s) = &w
}

func main() {
    tr := test_ref{}
    tr.init()
    s := tr.return_ref()
    setup(test_setup{
        s: s,
    })
    fmt.Println(**tr.v["a"]) //logging hello

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will require me to update the setup function, is there any way I could achive the same leaving the setup function untouched?

Comment: Based on you input "what you are returning is the address of the variable p." I figured that I could use a map[string]**string and return directly, I upvoted your answer If you update the answer I will mark it as accepted answer thanks https://go.dev/play/p/xM6Y3X4HQNT

Comment: That would require adressing the map value which is unadressable. Change the map in test_ref to store **string and it should work, though ugly

Comment: I added the double pointer solution to the answer